# What is the relationship between Celery and RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Is Celery mostly just a high level interface for message queues like RabbitMQ? I am trying to set up a system with multiple scheduled workers doing concurrent http requests, but I am not sure if I would need either of them. Another question I am wondering is where do you write the actual task in code for the workers to complete, if I am using Celery or RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 6):

RabbitMQ is indeed a message queue, and Celery uses it to send messages to and from workers. Celery is more than just an interface for RabbitMQ. Celery is what you use to create workers, kick off tasks, and define your tasks. It sounds like your use case makes sense for Celery/RabbitMQ. You create a task using the `@app.task` decorator. Check the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) for more info. In previous projects, I've set up a module for celery, where I define any tasks I need. Then you can pull in functions from other modules to use in your tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Celery is the task management framework--the API you use to schedule jobs, the code that gets those jobs started, the management tools (e.g. Flower) you use to monitor what's going on.

RabbitMQ is one of several "backends" for Celery. It's an oversimplification to say that Celery is a high-level interface to RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ is not actually required for Celery to run and do its job properly. But, in practice, they are often paired together, and Celery is a higher-level way of accomplishing some things that you could do at a lower level with just RabbitMQ (or another queue or message delivery backend).